# How to enable weak Cipher in python 3.7.4 with OpenSSL 1.1.1c?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, urllib3

The Server only supports weak ciphers. How can i connect  to the server via python?

The server has the following settings: (used sslyze 2-1-3)

- Certificate Information:
  Content

Signature Algorithm:               sha1

Public Key Algorithm:              RSA

Key Size:                          2048

Exponent:                          65537 (0x10001)

DNS Subject Alternative Names:     []

```
 Trust
   Hostname Validation:               OK - Certificate matches
   Android CA Store (9.0.0_r9):       FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: self signed certificate in certificate chain
   Apple CA Store (iOS 12, macOS 10.14, watchOS 5, and tvOS 12):FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: self signed certificate in certificate chain
   Java CA Store (jdk-12.0.1):        FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: self signed certificate in certificate chain
   Mozilla CA Store (2019-03-14):     FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: self signed certificate in certificate chain
   Windows CA Store (2019-05-27):     FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: self signed certificate in certificate chain
   Symantec 2018 Deprecation:         OK - Not a Symantec-issued certificate

   Verified Chain:                    ERROR - Could not build verified chain(certificate untrusted?)
   Received Chain Contains Anchor:    ERROR - Could not build verified chain(certificate untrusted?)
   Received Chain Order:              OK - Order is valid
   Verified Chain contains SHA1:      ERROR - Could not build verified chain (certificate untrusted?)

 Extensions
   OCSP Must-Staple:                  NOT SUPPORTED - Extension not found
   Certificate Transparency:          NOT SUPPORTED - Extension not found

   OCSP Stapling
                                      NOT SUPPORTED - Server did not send back an OCSP response
```

- TLS 1.2 Session Resumption Support:

With Session IDs:                  OK - Supported (5 successful, 0 failed, 0 errors, 5 total attempts).

With TLS Tickets:                  NOT SUPPORTED - TLS ticket not assigned

- SSLV3 Cipher Suites:

Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       RC4                                INSECURE - Supported

```
Preferred:
    None - Server followed client cipher suite preference.

 Accepted:
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                                         128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                                         128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                                         56 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                                    112 bits
    TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5                                   40 bits
    TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA                                40 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                                     56 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                                112 bits
```

- TLSV1 Cipher Suites:

Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       RC4                                INSECURE - Supported

```
 Preferred:
    None - Server followed client cipher suite preference.

 Accepted:
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                                         128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                                         128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                                         56 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                     256 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                                     128 bits
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                                    112 bits
    TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5                                   40 bits
    TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA                                40 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                                     56 bits
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                                112 bits
```

My Python code:

```
class noSSLVerification(HttpAuthenticated):
    def u2handlers(self):
        # use handlers from superclass
        handlers = HttpAuthenticated.u2handlers(self)

        ctx = ssl._create_unverified_context()
        ctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_ALL
        ctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
        ctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION
        ctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE

        # https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT
        # https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_ciphers.1.asp

        cipher = "RC4-MD5:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA:TLSv1.0:SSLv3"
        ctx.set_ciphers(cipher)

        handlers.append(HTTPSHandler(context=ctx))
        return handlers


url = "https://..."
transport = noSSLVerification()
client = Client(url, transport=transport)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's much better to use another certificate but sometimes there is no choise:

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext()
ctx.set_ciphers('ALL:@SECLEVEL=0')
```

I know it's very rude solution. Use it as start point

Comment: Hi, I tried your approach but unfortunately I still get the error message " self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] unknown error (_ssl.c:1076)

Comment: I had a slightly different problem to OP. Trying to connect to a server that only understands TLSv1 from a modern pyopenssl was resulting in error: 'No Ciphers Available'. This answer solved my problem and this question came up in all my searches, so just leaving this here in case anyone else in same position.